# issue with bootstrap specific nested grid layout to display pictures

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a specific nested grid layout to display pictures.
But I have an issue that I am unable to solve : my offset for xs screen is applied on sm, md screen.
You can see it in action here :

https://www.bootply.com/lpeNg9CcG3

My template is wrong, and what is the good one to only apply an offset on XS screen ?
Or this is an issue of bootstrap ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:
I have to overwrite my `col-xs-offset-1` with `col-sm-offset-0` and `col-md-offset-0`.

Indeed, this is a strange behavior of Bootstrap...

[Here is a working example](https://www.bootply.com/5RHVrmIOFm).

Comment: Yes, since the media query for `col-*-offset-*` is `min-width` instead of `max-width` so anything wider will be affected by the offset.